# ORAM: Is it generic?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, computation-models

Recently, plenty of researchers are looking at designing efficient data-oblivious algorithms. Roughly speaking, an algorithm is said to be data-oblivious if its data access patterns are independent of the input i.e. the data access pattern of the algorithm does not leak any information about the input of the algorithm. Some of the algorithms already looked at include sorting, BFS, minimum spanning tree and convex-hull. These data-oblivious algorithms have various applications for the cloud and efficient secure computation.

My question: Is ORAM a generic method to transform any non-data-oblivious algorithm to its data-oblivious counterpart?

Comment: These seem to be two separate quetions and I think they should be asked that way. You can always link between them to provide context. Stack Exchange doesn't work well when multiple questions are bundled together, since it can make it hard to select a single best answer.

Comment: I've edited the question to remove the 2nd question so this asks only one question per question. You can still post it separately (see the revision history to find it -- clicked "edited..." under the question).

Comment: Can you provide a definition of what it means for an algorithm to be data-oblivious?  (I'm aware of multiple definitions; I can guess which one you might mean, but I want to be sure I am using the right definition.)  Also, what have you tried, to solve this on your own?  Have you tried to prove that the answer is yes, or look for a counterexample?  What are your thoughts?  Sharing your thoughts about the question helps write answers at the right level for you.